# How to get the border color of a Button in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, junit, robolectric

I'm writing unit tests for a custom button component and i'm trying to assert the border color.

The custom button code for applying de border color:

CustomButton

```
val focusDrawable = GradientDrawable()
val defaultDrawable = GradientDrawable()

defaultDrawable.setStroke(mBorderWidth, mDisabledBorderColor)

...

this.background = RippleDrawable(
                     ColorStateList.valueOf(mFocusBackgroundColor),
                     defaultDrawable,
                     focusDrawable
                  )
```

how to (programmatically in kotlin/java) get the border color and perform an assert on that?